# Better opensource tools for profiling .Net based desktop application

Tags: .net, profiling, desktop

Net based desktop application to understand how the application is behaving on memory perspective. Please let me know any opensource tool to start the profiling and capturing the information.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio 2015 it's possible launch the Diagnostic Tools.

With the button 'Take Snapshot' in tab "memory usage' you can analize the memory.

For more info:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/01/16/diagnostic-tools-debugger-window-in-visual-studio-2015/